# a Riley, because I'm hype

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

My first is NOT lazy,

My second is NOT going to sit back and watch,

My third is "glib, deceptive, or foolish talk".

My full describes what two puzzles in one day are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this is right... 'Rileys' seem to have changed a bit since the last time I visited.

My first is NOT lazy

> **Hyper**

My second is NOT going to sit back and watch

> You're going to **act**

My third is "glib, deceptive, or foolish talk".

> Are you talking **jive**?

Writing two puzzles in a day might be:

> **Hyperactive** - which fits with your title, but is dropping the 'j' in keeping with the rules of Rileys?